# What to use for localization in JSPs with Spring?

Tags: jsp, localization, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a Spring MVC webapp that used messages_xx.properties files. Currently I use

`<fmt:message key="all.header.menu.items.start"/>`

in my files. I just saw another tutorial reccomending

`<spring:message code="all.header.menu.items.start"/>`

Can anyone tell the difference? What are PROs and CONs?

Thanks!

Comment: The <code>spring:message</code> appears to be functionally the same as the JSTL <code>fmt:message</code> tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rom the tag's doc [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html)

> It closely resembles JSTL's
>   fmt:message-tag, however, the
>   MessageSource classes can be
>   integrated with the Spring context.
>   Also, the spring:message- tag, works
>   with the locale support that comes
>   with Spring. Regards an HTML escaping
>   setting, either on this tag instance,
>   the page level, or the web.xml level.
>   Can also apply JavaScript escaping.
>
> If "code" isn't set or cannot be
>   resolved, "text" will be used as
>   default message. Thus, this tag can
>   also be used for HTML escaping of any
>   texts.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427105/dynamic-names-in-spring-internationalization) is another usage that is not supported by standard jstl

And [here](http://suniljoshi.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/springmessage-tag-and-resouce-bundle/) is 1 gotcha of using spring:message